# MVC app only rendering the _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, url-routing

I'm currently facing an issue with an MVC application I'm busy with, when testing the site in a local environment it shows the login page like it's supposed to as specified in the RouteConfig.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

But as soon as this gets uploaded the server it only renders the _layout.cshtml.

I have also attempted to specify the page in the application properties but this has not worked either.

Any advice or things to try would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

> Please note, when routing to the controller and views manually it all works fine, it's just the initial load of the site.

Comment: Do you have any IIS modules or ISS configuration who set a default page url ?

Comment: How is the site deployed? E.g., is it on a root domain `http://localhost/` or a sub folder like `http://localhost/MyApp`? If the later, then the issue could be down to an explicit root URL somewhere like `/Views/Page` instead of `Views/Page`

Comment: @DiskJunky Site/App is in the root folder, It's uploaded to a Virtual Private Server, but it gets pointed to from a Windows server. I will have a look at the explicit root URL but I'm sure I've been over everything.